# Need an output line by line as list after executing commands inside python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, os.system

As i'm executing commands inside python script as:

```
import os
import re

tes=list()
tes=os.system('p4 nc files @=4596830')

for line in tes:
     line2=re.findall('//depot/prod/DOT/dev/\w+((?:/\w*)*\.c)',line)
     print(line2)
```

i'm getting output as:

```
//depot/prod/DOT/dev/freebsd/10/sys/dev/nvme/nvme.c#16 - edit change 4596830 (text)
//depot/prod/DOT/dev/mgmtgateway/src/tables/card.smf#12 - edit change 4596830 (text)
//depot/prod/DOT/dev/ontap/prod/driver/scsi/pmcsas_init.c#81 - edit change 4596830 (text)

TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

but i need out as only files that that end with .c extension:

```
/freebsd/10/sys/dev/nvme/nvme.c
/ontap/prod/driver/scsi/pmcsas_init.c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.system` returns the status code of the call, not the `STDOUT, STDERR` streams. Python doesn't know how to iterate over an integer, so it raises an exception.

You can try using `subprocess` and piping `STDOUT, STDERR` to a custom stream, then casting that to a `list`.

```
import subprocess

call = subprocess.Popen("p4 nc files @=4596830", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout = call.communicate()[0]
files = stdout.split("\n")
```

Comment: tes=subprocess.Popen(["p4 nc files @=4596830"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)          output=test.communicate()[0]
          print(output)

Answer (score -1):

May be this can help

```
import os
import re

tes=list()
tes=os.system('p4 nc files @=4596830')

for line in tes:
     #line2=re.findall('//depot/prod/DOT/dev/\w+((?:/\w*)*\.c)',line)
     if ".c" in line:
         print(line)
```

Comment: OP is getting a `TypeError` in conjunction with the `os.system` call, so the main problem is there. Also, if ".c" is in a string, it doesn't mean the string *ends* with ".c" (though you could use `str.endswith(".c")`)